# Parse HTML in R with partial matches

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping

I need to parse the following HTML document:

```
<span class="revision-gradient shadowed">90</span>
<span class="revision-gradient not_shadowed">75</span>
<span class="revision-gradient shadowed">85</span>
<span class="revision-gradient blurred">60</span>
```

To return a list:

```
[90, 75, 85, 60]
```

I would typically use this code, but I'm not sure how to parse for partial matches:

```
document <- htmlParse(url)
myList <- unlist(lapply(document['//span[@class="revision-gradient"]'],xmlValue))
```

Comment: Are these the only elements in the XML document or are there additional tags which need to be ignored?

Comment: There's like 5 or 6 variations. Not a ton, so worst case scenario building off a list of different combinations would work.

Comment: are the variations you are interested in fixed or do they vary as well?

Comment: they are fixed.

Comment: Does it need to be a single pass or can you tolerate multiple passes? If the set of <spans> you interested in is fixed, why not hard code the lookup to only capture exact matches instead of worrying about partial matches? I am just thinking about what happens should the schema change and you start accepting data you do not want. Don't get me wrong, I like the question, I'm just thinking from a practicality standpoint. I'm also curious about the best answer. I am always leery of bad data leaking past filters.

Comment: No you make a really good point. Doing something like this definitely increases the odds of bad data making it through. But I feel good about being able to test the contents of the span to make sure it contains the right data, so I'm not too concerned. This is also a one time use. I plan on taking the hard code approach if I ever make something meant to be reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(rvest)

pg <- read_html('
<span class="revision-gradient shadowed">90</span>
<span class="revision-gradient not_shadowed">75</span>
<span class="revision-gradient shadowed">85</span>
<span class="revision-gradient blurred">60</span>
')

html_nodes(pg, "span.revision-gradient") %>% 
  html_text()
## [1] "90" "75" "85" "60"
```

or

```
html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//descendant-or-self::span[@class and 
           contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 
           ' revision-gradient ')]") %>% 
  html_text()
```

If you're stuck in `XML`-land:

```
library(XML)

doc <- htmlParse('
<span class="revision-gradient shadowed">90</span>
<span class="revision-gradient not_shadowed">75</span>
<span class="revision-gradient shadowed">85</span>
<span class="revision-gradient blurred">60</span>
')

xpathSApply(doc, "//descendant-or-self::span[@class and 
            contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 
            ' revision-gradient ')]", xmlValue)
```

If you want numeric values just call `as.numeric()` on the vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XML::xpathSApply`

```
myList <- xpathSApply(document, "//span", xmlValue)
```

And if you have more span paths, the following will be more robust

```
myList <- unlist(xpathSApply(document, "//span", function(x) {
    if (grepl("revision-gradient", xmlGetAttr(x, "class"))) {
        return(xmlValue(x))
    }
    NULL
}))
```

HTH